# How to remove XML data returned in PHP echo?

Tags: android, http

I have a php script which runs on a server which echoes 0 or 1. When I execute the script directly in the browser I get 0 or 1. But when I am doing the same through a HttpPost, I also get XML data about the server. I believe that the page source is also being returned in the response.
This is the Code:

```
    public static String executeHttpPost(String strURL, ArrayList postParameters) throws Exception 
{
    BufferedReader brStrReader = null;
    String strResult = "";
    try 
    {
        //Get the HTTPClient Instance
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();

        //Set the HTTP context to BasicHTTPContext
        HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();

        //Perform a HTTPPost with given URL
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(strURL);

        //Set the Entity
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

        //Get the HTTP response
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost, context);

        //Get the response into string

        strResult = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    }
    catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();             
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally 
    {
        //Check if BufferedStreamReader object is null
        if (brStrReader != null) 
        {
            try 
            {
                //Close the BufferedStreamReader
                brStrReader.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }           
    }
    return strResult;
```

This is the output:

```
    1<!-- www.serversfree.com Analytics Code --><script src="http://www.serversfree.com"></script><noscript><a title="Free hosting servers" href="http://www.serversfree.com">Free servers</a><a title="Free websites hosting server" href="http://www.serversfree.com">Free websites hosting server</a><a title="Free hosting server features" href="http://www.serversfree.com/server-features/">Free server features</a><a title="Free hosting" href="http://www.bugs3.com">Free hosting</a><a title="Page rank" href="http://www.1pagerank.com">Page rank</a></noscript>
```

Comment: Please share your code and the output you got.

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen: I have added the code and output. I am reusing the same code from another app. The other app is returning only 0 or 1.